# ExecutionEngineException while Debugging Tuple-Functions C#9/.NET 5.0 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I experienced a quite strange but reproducible Exception in Visual Studio 16.8.1 with .NET Framework 4.8.04084 and .NET Core 5.0.100 installed and running a .NET 5/C#9 Console Project.

Following code:

```csharp
using System;

namespace DebuggerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FunctionWithTuple();
            FunctionWithoutTuple();
        }

        static (string foo, int bar) FunctionWithTuple()
        {
            return ("", 5);
        }

        static string FunctionWithoutTuple()
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

When I add breakpoints inside the two functions `FunctionWith(out)Tuple()`, let the program run and edit the function e.g. by adding `Console.WriteLine("Hello");`, I expected that Visual Studio is able to execute the WriteLine and continue execution. But what I experience is, that adding the statement to the non-tuple function, it works, but adding it to the tuple-returning-function it throws an error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module.`.

I searched the web for this error but only found stuff regarding old VS versions and incompatibility with bitness etc. I found one source where `Debugging > Use Managed Compatibility Mode` should fix the problem. It does not for me. Same problem appears with lower .NET-Core project versions. (e.g. .net core 3.1)

This is what it looks like, when it fails:
[image: error appearing in visual studio]

.csproj is

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Clearly a bug (likely in Visual Studio). You should report it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: Vote on this issue please: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1254671/receiving-systemexecutionengineexception-while-deb.html